# Email or twitter alerts based on feed content?

Tags: temperature, rss

I've got temperature sensor data streamed in json, csv and atom formats via data.sparkfun.com. I have no access the sensor itself, though. Does anyone know a service or script, which could read this data and send me email (or twitter) alerts if the temperature rises or falls beyond specified limits?

Answer (score 1):

IFFFT.com combined with Particle.
Go to Part 2 in this article and configure Particle to monitor a variables that you configure:
https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/sparkfun-inventors-kit-for-photon-experiment-guide/experiment-2-with-the-touch-of-a-button

Comment: I can't see how spark can use atom, .csv or .json feeds as an input..

Comment: https://ifttt.com/channels/particle/triggers/35302811-monitor-a-variable

Comment: But to get a relevant particle stream,  you must connect your hardware to it via serial number and some other data, which is not .json or .atom, and I do not have it.